# Android Studio, R is error, can not resolved

Tags: java, android

I updated Android Studio to have 2.2 version. 
Unfortunately, I got this error (R is in red color)
I reinstall Android studio but no change.. R still in red color

I did not even write any code

```
syn gradle

Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/MainUser/Desktop/LastTry/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>


Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/MainUser/Desktop/LastTry/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/MainUser/Desktop/LastTry/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/MainUser/Desktop/LastTry/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

please I need help

Comment: Clean and Rebuild the Project.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. 
Go to File->Project Structure->app->dependencies and
remove all the dependencies except these:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0       Compile  
com.android.support:design:25.1.0             Compile  
junit:junit:4.12                              Test compile
```

This will change the dependencies structure under build.gradle.

Hope this works!!

Answer (score 0):

This may caused, your build to not compatible with current version.so, Open your root build.gradle file and change Gradle version like this

Old version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
```

New version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
```

You can find further details ,For Gradle version compatibility [see this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility).

Comment: @MajazenـG are you clean and Rebuild the project Manually ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in android studio. I fix it by doing **build - clean.** That usually works **BUT** if it doesnt, *save and exit AndStudio* and then restart